# Users as picklist values

Tags: picklist, user

Is there a way to have a multi picklist with user's names as the values? (Theoretically, this should automatically update if there is a new user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I would vote to close this as off topic, considering you have shown zero attempt to research this problem or solve it yourself. However, in this case there is an extremely simple option out there.

Our very own [@metadaddy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) put together a package that does just what you want: [Multiselect Picklist Visualforce Component](https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist). Here's a simple demo:

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="DemoController">
    <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Users"
        leftOptions="{!allUsers}"
        rightLabel="Selected Users"
        rightOptions="{!selectedUsers}"
        size="14"
        width="150px"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class DemoController
{
    public List<SelectOption> allUsers { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> selectedUsers { get; set; }
    public DemoController()
    {
        allUsers = new List<SelectOption>();
        selectedUsers = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (User user : [SELECT Name FROM User ORDER BY Name])
            allUsers.add(new SelectOption(user.Id, user.Name));
    }
}
```